# Run command in a child process

Tags: c, posix, child-process

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6744256/19634193) from SO, I try to find a version of fork()/exec()/wait() which:

- starts a child process;
- catches stdout, stderr and return code separately;
- properly handles all possible errors from system calls (e.g., out of memory, unable to open files, file not found) and makes sure no resources are leaked no matter what.
- won't crash even if child process is crashed and can report that child process crashed;
- Thread safe (`int exec()` only).

I failed to find such a implementation online as a reference so I write my own. But I am not sure if all edge cases are properly handled.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

int exec() {
int pipefd_out[2], pipefd_err[2];
    FILE* fp_out;
    FILE* fp_err;
    char buff[256];
    int status;

    if (pipe(pipefd_out) == -1) {
        // man 2 pipe
        perror("pipe()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (pipe(pipefd_err) == -1) {
        // man 2 pipe
        close(pipefd_out[0]);        
        close(pipefd_out[0]);
        perror("pipe()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    
    pid_t child_pid = fork(); //span a child process

    if (child_pid == -1) { // fork() failed, no child process created
        perror("fork(): ");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if (child_pid == 0) { // fork() succeeded, we are in the child process
        close(pipefd_out[0]);
        close(pipefd_err[0]);
        dup2(pipefd_out[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
        dup2(pipefd_err[1], STDERR_FILENO);


        char *const args[] = {"/bin/ls", "-l",
            "/path/that/definitely/does/not/exist/", NULL};
        execv(args[0], args);


        perror("execl()/execv()");
        // The exec() functions return only if an error has occurred.
        // The return value is -1, and errno is set to indicate the error.
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        // Have to exit() explicitly in case of execl() failure.
    }
    
    //Only parent gets here
    close(pipefd_out[1]);
    close(pipefd_err[1]);

    if ((fp_out = fdopen(pipefd_out[0], "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("fdopen()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if ((fp_err = fdopen(pipefd_err[0], "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("fdopen()");
        fclose(fp_out);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    printf("===== stdout =====\n");
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff) - 1, fp_out)) {            
        printf("%s", buff);
    }
    printf("===== stdout =====\n");

    printf("===== stderr =====\n");
    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff) - 1, fp_err)) {            
        printf("%s", buff);
    }    
    printf("===== stderr =====\n");
    fclose(fp_out);
    fclose(fp_err);

    // wait for the child process to terminate
    if (waitpid(child_pid, &status, 0) == -1) {
        perror("waitpid()");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
        printf("Child process exited normally, rc: %d\n", WEXITSTATUS(status));
    } else {
        printf("Child process exited unexpectedly ");
        if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
            printf("(terminated by a signal: %d)\n", WTERMSIG(status));
        } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) {
            printf("(stopped by delivery of a signal: %d)\n", WSTOPSIG(status));
        } else {
            printf("(unknown status: %d)\n", status);
        }
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s <0|1|2|3>\n", argv[0]);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    exec(argv);    
}
```

A complete version can be [found here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/tree/main/c-cpp/c/04_poc/06_subprocess), just in case you would like to compile it to see what exactly could happen.

Comment: Please don't add the improved code to your question after it's been answered.  You could post it as a new question for further review, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so it's clear what the answer is reviewing.

Comment: If this code is called with stdout or stderr closed, hilarious things will happen.

Comment: @SimonRichter wjat dp you mean "with stdout or stderr" closed? Do you mean the stdout/stderr of the parent program or the child program is closed? How exactly are they closed?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind, if fd 1 or 2 are closed when entering this code, the `pipe` function will use them.

Comment: @SimonRichter do you mean the child process strategically closes its stdout/stderr? If I get you correct, is it possible for me to revise my program to accommodate this case?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind, no, the parent process is called with stdout/stderr closed. Try `strace -f -o /dev/tty ./myprogram >&- 2>&-`.

Comment: Most programs that use the `fork()/exec()` pattern could simply use `posix_spawn()` instead.

Comment: @SimonRichter Sorry I am unable to translate what you said to a patch to my code--would it be possible for you to come up with some lines of code that fix the bug? It could be pseudocode as well.

Answer (score 7):

**Code risks invoking undefined behaviour:**

```
if (argc != 2) {
    printf("Usage: %s <0|1|2|3>\n", argv[0]);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Dereferencing `argv[0]` would invoke undefined behaviour if it was `NULL`.

Add a check for it.

```
/* Sanity check. POSIX requires the invoking process to pass a 
*  non-NULL argv[0].
*/
if (!argv[0]) {
    fputs ("A NULL argv[0] was passed in through an exec() system call.\n", stderr);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

**Don't use magic numbers:**

```
char buff[256];
```

Here, the magic number 256 should be a named constant.

```
#define BUFSIZE 256
```

It improves readability of the code and eases maintainability; requires just one change to the named constant instead of every instance of the number. See this SO question: [What are magic numbers, and why are they bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47882/20017547)

**Pointers to string literals should be declared with the `const` qualifier:**

```
// char *const args[] = {"/bin/ls", "-l",
            "/path/that/definitely/does/not/exist/", NULL};

const char *const args[] = {"/bin/ls", "-l", "/path/that/definitely/does/not/exist/", NULL};
```

Using `const` helps retain the string's integrity because you can only modify it with a new pointer to the string or by passing it to a function which modifies the string.

**Child processes should use `_exit()` instead of `exit()`:**

> The basic difference between `exit()` and `_exit()` is that the former
> performs clean-up related to user-mode constructs in the library, and
> calls user-supplied cleanup functions, whereas the latter performs
> only the kernel cleanup for the process.
>
> In the child branch of a `fork()`, it is normally incorrect to use
> `exit()`, because that can lead to stdio buffers being flushed twice,
> and temporary files being unexpectedly removed.

**Code doesn't fulfill all requirements:**

The return values of `dup2()`, `close()`, and `fclose()` are ignored.

From the man page for `close()`::

> **Dealing with error returns from `close()`:**
>
> A careful programmer will check the return value of `close()`,
> since it is quite possible that errors on a previous `write(2)`
> operation are reported only on the final `close()` that releases
> the open file description.  Failing to check the return value
> when closing a file may lead to silent loss of data.  This can
> especially be observed with NFS and with disk quota.

From the man page for `fclose()`:

> The `fclose()` function may also fail and set errno for any of the
> errors specified for the routines `close(2)`, `write(2)`, or
> `fflush(3)`.

**Calling `close()` on a closed descriptor could result in disastrous results:**

In `exec()`, we the have the following repeated calls to `close()` with the same file descriptor:

```
close(pipefd_out[0]);        
close(pipefd_out[0]);
```

From the man page:

> Retrying the `close()` after a failure return is the wrong thing to
> do, since this may cause a reused file descriptor from another
> thread to be closed.  This can occur because the Linux kernel
> always releases the file descriptor early in the close operation,
> freeing it for reuse; the steps that may return an error, such as
> flushing data to the filesystem or device, occur only later in
> the close operation.

The above is true for a successful `close()` operation.

**Save `errno` if it is required for later use:**

```
if (pipe(pipefd_err) == -1) {
    // man 2 pipe
    close(pipefd_out[0]);        
    close(pipefd_out[0]);
    perror("pipe()");
}
```

The calls to `close()` may overwrite the value of `errno`. If the value is required for later use, it's good practice to save it as soon as possible before any other function calls.

```
if (pipe(pipefd_err) == -1) {
    // man 2 pipe
    int saved_errno = errno;

    close(pipefd_out[0]);        
    close(pipefd_out[0]);
    errno = saved_errno;
    perror("pipe()");
}
```

Or perhaps just call `perror()` before calling `close()`:

```
if (pipe(pipefd_err) == -1) {
    // man 2 pipe
    perror("pipe()");
    close(pipefd_out[0]);        
    close(pipefd_out[0]);
}
```

Comment: For the magic number, my thought is that this function will be a part of some larger programs. So I would like it to be as self-contained as possible. But anyway, the `#define` is added to my revision [here](https://github.com/alex-lt-kong/the-nitty-gritty/blob/main/c-cpp/c/04_poc/06_subprocess/main.c)

Comment: On "Dealing with error returns from `close():`", it is not very clear per `man close` whether I should still check the return value of `close()` if I `write()` nothing before that. My understanding of `man`'s wording is that `close()` could only fail due to previous `write()` call. Any further guidance on this?

Comment: one more question I am not sure is about `close()`. Let's say there is no error and everything works as expected: I `pipe(pipefd)` a new `pipefd` and `fork()` my program. How many times should `close()` be called? Four times or twice only? I try to follow your idea to check the retval of `close()`, it complains `Bad file descriptor`. Does it mean that I `close()` it more than I should?

Comment: About the first question: I was unable to understand it. Why would your source file be included in a project? And there are other ways to have named constants in C, namely `const int`s and `enum`s. Or the new `constexpr` in C23. About the second question: See this SO question: https://lwn.net/Articles/576478/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/19056309/20017547. About the last question: see my edited answer.

Comment: regarding the times of `close()`, perhaps I didnt make myself clear. When I say 4 times, I mean I call `close(pipefd[0])` and `close(pipefd[1])` in the parent process and `close(pipefd[0])` and `close(pipefd[1])` in the child process. Is this the proper way to handle them? (Should I call `close(pipefd[1]);`/`close(pipefd[0]);` in child process? If so, where should they be done?)

Comment: `BUFSIZE` is not the best name since on may systems it is already defined in stdio.h.

Comment: `stdio.h` defines `BUFSIZ`, note the lack of `E`. So we're safe.

Comment: My apologies, it was clear enough. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/64867424

Comment: The sanity check that the OS doesn’t do something it’s specified never to do feels a little odd to me. If it passes a null pointer in `argv[0]`, do I trust it to execute system calls properly, either? I might handle that more concisely with `assert(argv[0]);`

Comment: The last recommendation looks wrong, as it fails to close `fp_out`.

Comment: @Ben Good grief. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Davislor AFAIK, nothing stops a malicious user from running your program with argc == 0 on typical existing POSIX systems. The GNU's implementation of `ls` has a check for it.

Comment: I have a more concrete question on a revised version of this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75705467/should-i-call-close-in-poll-loop). You may take a look if you are also interested in it.

Answer (score 5):

We need to enable more compiler warnings - these problems are trivially fixed:

```
gcc-12 -std=c17 -fPIC -gdwarf-4 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wwrite-strings -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Warray-bounds -Wmissing-braces -Wconversion  -Wstrict-prototypes -fanalyzer       283851.c    -o 283851
283851.c:10:5: warning: function declaration isn’t a prototype [-Wstrict-prototypes]
   10 | int exec() {
      |     ^~~~
283851.c: In function ‘exec’:
283851.c:44:31: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   44 |         char *const args[] = {"/bin/ls", "-l",
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~
283851.c:44:42: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   44 |         char *const args[] = {"/bin/ls", "-l",
      |                                          ^~~~
283851.c:45:13: warning: initialization discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   45 |             "/path/that/definitely/does/not/exist/", NULL};
      |             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
283851.c:101:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
  101 | }
      | ^
```

---

Our file-descriptor clean-up is lacking.  Here, we close the read end twice, but leave the write end open:

> ```
> if (pipe(pipefd_err) == -1) {
>     // man 2 pipe
>     close(pipefd_out[0]);
>     close(pipefd_out[0]);
>     perror("pipe()");
>     return EXIT_FAILURE;
> }
> ```

And here, we leave all four pipe descriptors open:

> ```
> if (child_pid == -1) { // fork() failed, no child process created
>     perror("fork(): ");
>     return EXIT_FAILURE;
> }
> ```

There's a lot more missing `close()` calls (even in the success path).

This kind of error handling is often best handled using the otherwise-shunned `goto` statement.  Set up a sequence of clean-ups that are the reflection of the initialisations:

```
err_out_file:
        fclose(fp_out);
err_err_fds:
        close(pipefd_err[0]);
        close(pipefd_err[1]);
err_out_fds:
        close(pipefd_out[0]);        
        close(pipefd_out[1]);
err_initial:
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
```

That ensures that error exits at each stage will clean up all the resources from preceding stages:

```
    if (pipe(pipefd_out) == -1) {
        perror("pipe()");
        goto err_initial;
    }
    if (pipe(pipefd_err) == -1) {
        perror("pipe()");
        goto err_out_fds;
    }
    
    pid_t child_pid = fork(); //span a child process

    if (child_pid == -1) { // fork() failed, no child process created
        perror("fork()");
        goto err_err_fds;
    }
```

```
    if ((fp_out = fdopen(pipefd_out[0], "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("fdopen()");
        goto err_err_fds;
    }
    if ((fp_err = fdopen(pipefd_err[0], "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("fdopen()");
        goto err_out_file;
    }
```

---

Reading all the output stream before reading all the error stream is fine for this simple `ls`, but could cause a deadlock when the child writes more than a pipe's capacity to error stream before it closes the output stream, here:

> ```
> printf("===== stdout =====\n");
> while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff) - 1, fp_out)) {            
>     printf("%s", buff);
> }
> printf("===== stdout =====\n");
>
> printf("===== stderr =====\n");
> while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff) - 1, fp_err)) {            
>     printf("%s", buff);
> }    
> printf("===== stderr =====\n");
> ```

We need to be using `select()` to correctly interleave reads of both streams.

---

The `main()` function is misleading.  It insists on the user supplying an argument, but that's never used, since `exec` ignores its optional arguments (writing `int exec(void)` would have detected that).  Also, we ignore the return value from `exec()`, even though that's *exactly* what we should be returning from `main()`.

---

On the style side, I strongly dislike all the whitespace at ends of many lines.

Also, there's no need in modern C to declare all variables at the start of their enclosing scope.  Prefer to declare variables where they can be initialised with values, to eliminate any chance of using them before they are assigned.

---

Overall, this looks like a good beginning to this function, but it appears rushed and a bit sloppy.  We need to fix the releasing of resources and eliminate the possible deadlock when reading the two streams.

Comment: Is `int exec()` an obsolescent feature or undefined behaviour?

Comment: Prototypes were introduced in 1989, so it's fairly safe in 2023 to describe such non-prototype declarations as "obsolescent".  I certainly don't recommend using them, and haven't written code to cater to both old-style and new-style declarations for at least a quarter century.

Comment: BTW @Haris, are the spelling mistakes deliberate in your profile quote? Or should it say "_not to jump on **them** whenever **they** make an error_"?  (Oh, the irony!)

Comment: I added the revised version to the top of the question, without removing the original one, to keep the context. On the `select()` part, how is it done?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind That's not the standard practice here, so I've reverted the question edit and added a comment with suggestions.  Using `select()` well is too large a topic to answer in comments here, so I suggest you read its man page and any on-line resources you find, then give it a go yourself (you'll need the descriptors, not `FILE` pointers).  I suggest posting a new review request when you have it working.

Comment: @TobySpeight They were actually unintentional, but I'd keep one just for the sake of it. ;-)

Comment: @D.J.Elkind Read the I/O multiplexing section of the UNP book (I believe it's the sixth chapter), or this man page: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select_tut.2.html , or the numerous questions already asked on SO.

Comment: would `poll()`/`epoll()`be a "better" alternative to `select()`?

Comment: It's a while since I've used either, to be honest, so you'll have to do your own research and make the choice.  Sorry that's not a particularly helpful response @D.J.Elkind, but it's all I can do right now!

Comment: @TobySpeight In the current state (i.e., using `hile(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff) - 1, fp_out))`), there is one more aspect that I am not sure. Is it possible for a program to "close" its stdout/stderr before the program exits? If this is possible, say a program totally closes its stdout, does some stuff, and opens its stdout again, will my program miss some output?

Comment: @D.J.Elkind `select()` vs `poll()` is irrelevant in this case. I, for one, wouldn't recommend `poll()`, not when there are just a handful of file descriptors to monitor.

Comment: @Haris I ask about `select()`/`poll()`/`epoll` because `man select` mentioned it as follows: select() can monitor only file descriptors numbers that are less than FD_SETSIZE; poll(2) and epoll(7) do not have this limitation.  See BUGS.

Comment: Yes, and that argument is irrelevant in this case. You only have a few file descriptors to monitor. `FD_SETSIZE` is defined as 1024 (or higher) on most platforms.

Comment: A program can close its output streams before it exits.  But given these are anonymous pipes, then it's not possible to re-open them and send more output to the parent.  So that's not something you need to consider.

Comment: Hi @TobySpeight, I revised my code to incorporate `poll()` to it. However, before I can get it reviewed, I faced a more concrete issue which is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75705467/should-i-call-close-in-poll-loop/). Perhaps you are also interested in this as well.

Answer (score 4):

### Use `posix_spawn`

Or possibly `posix_spawnp`. It’s in [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn.html) precisely to take care of this.  You don’t need to reinvent the wheel here.

You pass this system call a spawn attributes object.  For example, to remap arbitrary file descriptors such as your pipes to the child process’ standard input and output, you would use [`posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn_file_actions_adddup2.html) twice to initialize a file actions object that you pass to `posix_spawn`.  Or to redirect files as standard input or standard output, you would use a sequence of calls including  [`posix_spawn_file_actions_addopen`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/posix_spawn_file_actions_addopen.html).

### Request the POSIX API

You apparently are using a library that doesn’t declare `exec` for you, and writing your own, pre-ANSI declaration.

Instead, add to the top of your file, before any library headers,

```c
 #define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
 #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 700
```

Or add the corresponding `-D` options to your makefile.

The functions you need, including `exec()`, will now be declared in `<unistd.h>`.  On Linux, you should also be able to use the portable API in `man -s 3p exec`, etc.

Comment: This does appear to be something worth exploring. But actually I wanted to do a bit more than what I described in the question. For example, does `posix_spawn` support timeout? Say I want the child process to run for no more than one min, otherwise it should be killed. (I did a brief search but doesn't seem to find many results on this)

Comment: @D.J.Elkind It returns a PID, which can be used in all the same ways as the PID from `fork()``, including sending a signal and doing a timed wait. They can also synchronize using shared memory, for example a timed wait on a barrier.

Answer (score 2):

**Unnedded `-1`**

No need to subtract 1.

> The `fgets` function reads at most one less than the number of characters specified by n from the stream pointed to by stream into the array pointed to by s.

```
// while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff) - 1, fp_err)) {            
while(fgets(buff, sizeof buff, fp_err)) {
```

Comment: I have a more concrete question on a revised version of this code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75705467/should-i-call-close-in-poll-loop). You may take a look if you are also interested in it.